# How emit event to LoadingOverlay component from Axios custom component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have this architectural components...

```
LoginPage                  => Form      
useAuth                    => Controller
useAuthenticationServices  => Services
useOpenApi                 => Custom Axios with interceptors
```

When I submit data ((1.2) handleSubmitClick) I can get data from server API (1.2 > 2,2 > 3.2 > 4 axios...),so this work fine. My problem is that cant use not kind of hook in my useOpenApi component (useContext, useState, useEffect...I always get hook error.) its a ok, I now why. But I need change status component by (4.1) event when axios begin request (setLoading -> true). which better aproach to do this? I now I can change css from dom (`document.body.classList.add('loading-indicator')`) but I belive is worst way.

```
(1) const LoginPage = (props) => {
     (1.1) const handleSubmitClick = async (props, context) => {
        (1.2) const ret = await doLogin(state.username, state.password)
        ..
        
(2) const useAuth = () => {     
     (2.1) const doLogin = async (username, password) => {
        (2.2) const ret = await login(username, password)
        ..
        
(3) const useAuthenticationServices = () => {
    (3.1) const login = async (email, password) => {
        (3.2) const ret = await openApi.post('/useraccounts/Login', payload)
        ..
            
(4) const useOpenApi = () => {          
        const openApi = .create({
            baseURL: process.env.SERVICE_URL
        });
        
        (4.1) openApi.interceptors.request.use(async config => {
        ..
        
        return config;
    }
```

basically I have

```
        <ToastContainer...
          <MyCustomContext....  
            <LoadingOverlay....  <<<need set isLoading = true
                <LoginPage  -> call AxiosCustom(openApi -> 4.1)
```

There is another way a set context im my AxiosCustom to generate/emit event do LoadingOverlay component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can share a parent level variable(isLoading) among the two child level components. Then, use the useEffect hook to watch the variable in LoadingOverlay Component.

```
function ParentComponent() {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = false;

    const modifyIsLoading = (value) => {
       setIsLoading(value);
    }
    return <LoadingOverlay isLoading={isLoading} modifyIsLoading={modifyIsLoading}>
        <LoginPage modifyIsLoading={modifyIsLoading}
        </LoginPage>
     </LoadingOverlay>
}

function LoginPage(props){
     const axiosCall = () => {
         doAxiosCall().then(res => {
              props.modifyIsLoading(true);
         })
     }
}

function LoadingOverlay(props){
     useEffect(() => {
         console.log(props.isLoading) // changes every time the parent isLoading value changes
     }, [props.isLoading])
}
```